# QDomElement QDomDocument::documentElement() return type is not reference,how it can change xml in QDomDocument?

Tags: xml, qt, dom

As my title expressed, I use QDomDocument read-in xml file and use his function `QDomDocument::documentElement()` to achieve xml's root node `Element`. Like this:

```
QDomElement devices = docDetails_.documentElement();
QDomElement device = docDetails_.createElement("Device");
QDomAttr id = docDetails_.createAttribute("id");
id.setValue(QString::number(deviceInfo.id));
device.setAttributeNode(id);
devices.appendChild(device);
```

But the function's return type is not a reference type, why `appendChild()` can change `QDomDocument`'s content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdomdocument.html) says (emphasis mine):

> The parsed XML is represented internally by a tree of objects that can
>   be accessed using the various QDom classes. **All QDom classes only
>   reference objects in the internal tree**. The internal objects in the
>   DOM tree will get deleted once the last QDom object referencing them
>   and the QDomDocument itself are deleted.

So, calling `QDomNode::appendChild` on some QDom element will change its document internal xml tree.

Comment: sorry，I still don't understand.I mean,if  `QDomDocument::documentElement()` return what isn't a _reference_,so is a _duplicate_.Then operating on _duplicate_ shouldn't make sense to content of `QDomDocument`.

Comment: Yes, it is a different C++ object, but it is internally implemented to be linked with the `QDomDocument` internal structure.

Comment: I also guess so.Could you give me a briefly example about internally impementation you said.

Answer (score 0):

```
auto a = doc.documentElement();
auto b = doc.documentElement();
```

use qtcreator debug and see a and b, expand them and see impl, you can see same address.

so, They use the same data structure, change a or b will also change doc.

```
QDomElement QDomDocument::documentElement() const
{
    if (!impl)
        return QDomElement();
    return QDomElement(IMPL->documentElement());
}
QDomElementPrivate* QDomDocumentPrivate::documentElement()
{
    QDomNodePrivate *p = first;
    while (p && !p->isElement())
        p = p->next;
    return static_cast<QDomElementPrivate *>(p);
}
```